# Powerpoint slides: how to copy my combobox and textbox controls on one slide to a another slide, same presentation?

Tags: vba, copy, controls, powerpoint, slide

Powerpoint Slides: Trying to create duplicate slides so that user can, on each slide, 
1. select an option 
2. enter free text.

I have the following VBA and controls in Slide2, I want to copy everything, including combobox and textbox, from slide2 for any/all subsequent slides. I want an easy way to do this. just copying or duplicating the slides will not allow users to make selections or add free text on any slides after slide2 (the original). Although the controls still APPEAR on the subsequent slides, no selection or typing can be made. Subsequent slides contain the VBA script but not any controls copied over? I'm new-ish to this so not sure all of my language is correct here.(i used to know how to do all this stuff about 12 years ago, lol)

Please tell me there is a fast and easy way to do this! It's taken me all afternoon to teach myself the current script (combo/text boxes) and research a slide copy fix, to no avail.

Here's my simple script for the combo box and textbox from slide2.

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
        With ComboBox1
            .AddItem "Select One", 0
            .AddItem "Accept", 1
            .AddItem "Reject", 2
            ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand everything you want, but this duplicates slide 1, including all the code belonging to the controls in the slide:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate
```

Let me know if there's something I'm missing